# How can I get mutt/neomutt to not close an empty edit field when backspace is pressed?

Tags: neomutt

I used [mutt-wizard](https://github.com/LukeSmithxyz/mutt-wizard) to configure neomutt. When I edit e.g. the from-address by pressing `<Esc>f` in the `Compose` view (just before sending my mail) it let's me edit the field. The command line becomes an edit line, this is below the status line.

If I delete the address completely by pressing backspace, it closes the edit line and leaves the address unchanged, if I want to delete more characters than there are. This happens easily and is mildly annoying.

I guess backspace is bount to close the edit operation/leave/unselect the field?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvHwb.jpg

I would like to enter a new address after I deleted the old one and pressed backspace more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the example you shared I noticed you're using neomutt. Mutt and Neomutt behaviour differs in this particular case.

#### References

**Neomutt:**

After erasing all characters next backspace restores previous content and cancels the edit.
For more information about it see discussion in issue #2002 related to this change: [Backspace while editing any header field wraps around](https://github.com/neomutt/neomutt/issues/2002)

**Mutt:**

After erasing all characters you can press backspace and mutt stays in editing the header.

---

#### Answer

Since NeoMutt 2020-03-13 there is `abort_backspace` option allowing You to change the behaviour. See [release notes](https://neomutt.org/2020/03/13/release#wrench-changed-config).

`set abort_backspace = no`

Or Neomutt knows readline bindings: *unix-line-discard* `Ctrl-u` removes all characters from the line, and keeps you in the prompt.

Comment: Hehe now I am perfectly used to the workaround, `Ctrl-u`. Thanks for your answer and sorry it took me so long to accept it.